# Python - How to clear spaces from a text

Tags: python, string

In Python, I have a lot of strings, containing spaces.
I would like to clear all spaces from the text, except if it is in quotation marks.

Example input:

```
This is "an example text" containing spaces.
```

And I want to get:

```
Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.
```

`line.split()` is not good, I think, because it clears all of spaces from the text.

What do you recommend?

Comment: You will need to do some kind of parsing to allow quoted strings to remain untouched - but you are not clear here. Should `'` quoted substrings be honoured, for example? How should unclosed quotes be handled?

Comment: just "spaces accepted here" 
All is closed.

Comment: Thank you.
And how can I replace this spaces with **?

Comment: That is a new question, not a comment on this one.

Comment: @TűzállóFöldgolyó why, if I might ask?

Answer (score 5):

For the simple case that only `"` are used as quotes:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is "an example text" containing spaces.'
>>> re.sub(r' (?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', "", s)
'Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.'
```

**Explanation:**

```
[ ]      # Match a space
(?=      # only if an even number of spaces follows --> lookahead
 (?:     # This is true when the following can be matched:
  [^"]*" # Any number of non-quote characters, then a quote, then
  [^"]*" # the same thing again to get an even number of quotes.
 )*      # Repeat zero or more times.
 [^"]*   # Match any remaining non-quote characters
 $       # and then the end of the string.
)        # End of lookahead.
```

Answer (score 4):

There is probably a more elegant solution than this, but:

```
>>> test = "This is \"an example text\" containing spaces."
>>> '"'.join([x if i % 2 else "".join(x.split())
              for i, x in enumerate(test.split('"'))])
'Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.'
```

We split the text on quotes, then iterate through them in a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw). We remove the spaces by splitting and rejoining if the index is odd (not inside quotes), and don't if it is even (inside quotes). We then rejoin the whole thing with quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Using `re.findall` is probably the more easily understood/flexible method:

```
>>> s = 'This is "an example text" containing spaces.'
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'(?:".*?")|(?:\S+)', s))
'Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.'
```

You could (ab)use the `csv.reader`:

```
>>> import csv
>>> ''.join(next(csv.reader([s.replace('"', '"""')], delimiter=' ')))
'Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.'
```

Or using `re.split`:

```
>>> ''.join(filter(None, re.split(r'(?:\s*(".*?")\s*)|[ ]', s)))
'Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions!

```
import cStringIO, re
result = cStringIO.StringIO()
regex = re.compile('("[^"]*")')
text = 'This is "an example text" containing spaces.'

for part in regex.split(text):
    if part and part[0] == '"':
        result.write(part)
    else:
        result.write(part.replace(" ", ""))
return result.getvalue()
```

Comment: `StringIO` seems unnecessary here - why not just use a list and `"".join()`?

Comment: Just because it faster and requires less memory. Of course you can use ``join``.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with csv as well:

```
import csv

out=[]
for e in csv.reader('This is "an example text" containing spaces. '):
    e=''.join(e)
    if e==' ': continue
    if ' ' in e: out.extend('"'+e+'"')
    else: out.extend(e)

print ''.join(out)
```

Prints `Thisis"an example text"containingspaces.`

Answer (score 0):

```
'"'.join(v if i%2 else v.replace(' ', '') for i, v in enumerate(line.split('"')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quotation_mark = '"'                                                            
space = " "                                                                             
example = 'foo choo boo "blaee blahhh" didneid ei did '                         
formated_example = ''                                                           

if example[0] == quotation_mark:                                                           
    inside_quotes = True                                                       
else:                                                                           
    inside_quotes = False                                                        

for character in example:                                                          
    if inside_quotes != True:                                                   
        formated_example += character                                              
    else:                                                                       
        if character != space:                                                     
            formated_example += character                                          
    if character == quotation_mark:                                                
        if inside_quotes == True:                                               
            inside_quotes = False                                               
        else:                                                                   
            inside_quotes = True                                                

print formated_example
```

Comment: I'll repeat my comment for some of the other answers: ["String concatenation is best done with ''.join(seq) which is an O(n) process. In contrast, using the '+' or '+=' operators can result in an O(n**2) process because new strings may be built for each intermediate step. The CPython 2.4 interpreter mitigates this issue somewhat; however, ''.join(seq) remains the best practice."](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/)